# How to get multiple selected items from the drop down in xforms

Tags: xforms

I have a select control with multiple selection in xforms, when i select more than one item it is mapped to single node with space separated value. but i wanted multiple items selected as multiple nodes

Comment: Why is it nececessary for them to all be different nodes?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work with plain XForms, since [xforms:select](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-xforms-20091020/#ui-selectMany) is defined to be bound to a single node. You will have to split up the selected values by postprocessing the node value, for example by reacting on the `onValueChange` event, or by transforming the resulting instance using XSLT.